# JQuery DatePicker Date Formatting issue when copying

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Look to just copy the Year to the 2nd input - not the entire date. Here is the HTML so 1st input - date format is correct. 2nd input - date format needs to be just the year and not the whole date.

look here
http://jsfiddle.net/xyp7khfe/13/

```
<input id="sdate" />
<input id="edate" />
```

and here is the JQUERY

```
$('#sdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function () {
        $('#edate').val(this.value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the value with the `.val()` method, you could use the [`setDate` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) to update the value while taking the `dateFormat` property value into consideration:

```
$('#edate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(this.value));
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/skn4gmbL/)

```
$('#sdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    onSelect: function () {
        $('#edate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(this.value));
    }
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can create a date based on the value and then use the [`.getFullYear()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear):

```
$('#edate').val(new Date(this.value).getFullYear());
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zox16pgp/)

```
$('#sdate').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  onSelect: function() {
    $('#edate').val(new Date(this.value).getFullYear());
  }
});
```